# Seeking USB hard drive SMART diagnostic tool

Tags: hard-drive, smart, diagnostic

I have a pair of hardrives from a RAID which was warning of degraing on a desktop machine.

That machien is out of commision & whether I repeair it depands on whether I can still use 0, 1, or 2 of the drives.

Can anyone reccommend an S.M.A.R.T hard drive diagnotic tool which I can run from my laptop with the drives connected as external USB drives?

Btw, my laptop currently doesn't recognize its CD driver, so I can't use a live CD.

Comment: If you cannot read smart values using software recommended here, then the usb chip in your adapter does not support pass-through ATA commands, which are needed to read smart data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html), it recognizes USB drives.

Comment: it does not recognize my external drive, coupled over USB

Comment: sorry, worked for my external hdd